# increment dimension of np.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I want to increment the dimension of an ndarray like this:

```
from r = [[1 2]
          [3 4]] 

to r = [[1 2 0]
        [3 4 0]
        [0 0 0]]
```

if I use r.resize((3, 3), refcheck=False) i get:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NumPy's `pad` function:

```
import numpy as np
np.pad(r,(0,1))
```

This will pad with zeros `r` with padding size of 1 at the end of the rows and columns, and will not pad at the beginning (as we set to 0 the padding size there).

Answer (score 2):

You simply can define a new nparray and map the old one to it:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

reshaped_array = np.zeros((3, 3))
reshaped_array[:2, :2] = x
```

output:

```
array([[1., 2., 0.],
       [3., 4., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Also doable. Note that this solution involves the creation of another array in memory which will result in overhead. For small arrays this solution should be fine.

Comment: It's true @GilPinsky. I assume it will be a small array. for larger arrays, it is not efficient.

Comment: @Gil, so does your use of `pad`.  GIven the desired layout of the data, there's no in-place option.  Look at `x.ravel()` - before and after padding to see why.

Comment: @Gil, what optimizations does `pad` do?  Last I looked it was pure Python code.